# boost.asio - do i need to use locks if sharing database type object between different async handlers?

Tags: c++11, concurrency, boost-asio

I'm making a little server for a project, I have a log handler class which contains a log implemented as a map and some methods to act on it (add entry, flush to disk, commit etc..)

This object is instantiated in the server Class, and I'm passing the address to the session so each session can add entries to it.

The sessions are async, the log writes will happen in the async_read callback. I'm wondering if this will be an issue and if i need to use locks?

The map format is `map<transactionId map<sequenceNum, pair<head, body>>`, each session will access a different transactionId, so there should be no clashes as far as i can figure. Also hypothetically, if they were all writing to the same place in memory -- something large enough that the operation would not be atomic; would i need locks? As far as I understand each async method dispatches a thread to handle the operation, which would make me assume yes. At the same time I read that one of the great uses of async functions is the fact that synchronization primitives are not needed. So I'm a bit confused.

First time using ASIO or any type of asynchronous functions altogether, and i'm not a very experienced coder. I hope the question makes sense! The code seems to run fine so far, but i'm curios if it's correct.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asynchronous handlers will only be invoked in application threads processing the `io_service` event loop via `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()`, or `poll_one()`.  The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html) states:

> Asynchronous completion handlers will only be called from threads that are currently calling `io_service::run()`.

Hence, for a non-thread safe shared resource:

- If the application code only has one thread, then there is neither concurrency nor race conditions.  Thus, no additional form of synchronization is required.  Boost.Asio refers to this as an [*implicit* strand](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html).
- If the application code has multiple threads processing the event-loop and the shared resource is only accessed within handlers, then synchronization needs to occur, as multiple threads may attempt to concurrently access the shared resource.  To resolve this, one can either:

  - Protect the calls to the shared resource via a synchronization primitive, such as a mutex.  This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14310294/1053968) covers using mutexes within handlers.
  - Use the same strand to [`wrap()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/wrap.html) the ReadHandlers.  A strand will prevent concurrent invocation of handlers dispatched through it.  For more details on the usage of strands, particularly for composed operations, such as `async_read()`, consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12801042/1053968) answer.
  - Rather than posting the entire ReadHandler into the strand, one could limit interacting with the shared resource to a specific set of functions, and these functions are posted as CompletionHandlers to the same strand.  This subtle difference between this and the previous solution is the granularity of synchronization.
- If the application code has multiple threads and the shared resource is accessed from threads processing the event loop and from threads not processing the event loop, then synchronization primitives, such as a mutex, needs to be used.

Also, even if a shared resource is small enough that writes and reads are always atomic, one should prefer using explicit and proper synchronization.  For example, although the write and read may be atomic, without proper memory fencing to guarantee memory visibility, a thread may not observe a chance in memory even though the actual memory has chanced.  Boost.Asio's will perform the proper [memory barriers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/allocation.html) to guarantee visibility.  For more details, on Boost.Asio and memory barriers, consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16868674/1053968) answer.